# java opengl: glDrawElements() with >32767 vertices

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, unsigned, short

I have a complex model that has >32767 vertices. now, the indices can only be passed to opengl as type GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE or GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT. java has no concept of unsigned, so the unsigned short option maps to simply (signed) short, which is 16 bits, or +32767. when I specify the vertices, i need to pass opengl a short[], where the values in the array point to a vertex in the vertice array. however, if there are >32767 vertices, the value won't fit in the short[].

Is there another way to specify the indices? code snippet is below,

```
    short[] shorts = ... read the indices ...;
    ...
    ShortBuffer indicesBuffer = null;
    ByteBuffer ibb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indices.length * Short.SIZE / 8);
    ibb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    indicesBuffer = ibb.asShortBuffer();
    indicesBuffer.put(indices);
    indicesBuffer.position(0);
    ...
    gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, numOfIndices, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indicesBuffer);
    ...
```

Comment: by the way this happens to be on the android platform using opengl-es 1.0.

Comment: I think most of the phone can't handle that complexity with reasonable performance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't used OpenGL from Java so I'm speculating here, but there's a good chance that you can just use the negative numbers whose binary reprentation is the same as the unsigned positive numbers you really want.  You're giving GL some byte pairs and telling it to interpret them as unsigned, and as long as they have the right value when interpreted that way, it should work.  It doesn't matter if Java thought they meant something different when it stored those bits in memory.

If you're iterating, just ignore the wraparound and keep on incrementing.  When you get to -1, you're done.

If you're calculating the index numbers as ints (which don't have this range problem) and then casting to short, subtract 65536 from any number that's greater than 32767.

Comment: yes, i came to the same conclusion. you'sort of odd for a language that is all high and mighty about type safety. i initially used char, as that is essentially an unsigned short. i am calculating the indices as ints then converting just to make it simpler and ensure

Comment: thanks, i ended up just treating them as ints them casting to short with the cveat you provided above, although i wonder if the cast operation would take care of that automatically. makes you wonder what the folks that created the java bindings were thinkings ... java being all high and mighty about type safety and all.

Comment: Don't talk of OpenGL, talk of OpenGL ES :). ES doesn't support GL_UNSIGNED_INT for indices, only GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE and GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, and this has nothing to do with Java.

Comment: following up, the subtraction is not necessary when converting to an int. the cast operation handles it. e.g., int 32768 cast to a short is -32768.

Comment: @farble1670: I've always felt that the lack of unsigned types in Java is a design misfeature.